# find all word with apostrophe using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a hard time solving this problem
I need to get all the word that contains apostrophe, sometimes the single used as apostrophe

This is my regex:

```
[\u0027\u2019]
```

And this is my sample words:

```
'Chapert 2' 
Chapter's
chapters'
```

My expected output is

```
Chapter's
chapters'
```

But my code right now is it gets all the word that contains apostrophe or single qoute. How can i get all the word that doesn't start with apostrophe or single qoute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the desired result:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[^'].*'.*$");
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "'Chapert 2'", "Chapter's", "chapters'" };

foreach(var item in list)
{
    if (rgx.IsMatch(item))
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

### Breakdown

- `^` - Start of string.
- `[^']` - One character that is NOT the `'`.
- `.*` - Zero or more any characters.
- `'` - There has to be at leas one `'`
- `.*` - Zero or more any characters again to end the string.
- `$` - End of string.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and details about the regex. I choose this answer because of the completeness.

Answer (score 1):

`^[^']` is enough.

- The first `^` matches the beginning of a string
- `[^…]` matches every character except the ones inside brackets

So `^[^']` matches strings that start with a non-apostrophe character.

Comment: This won't work. Not only they shouldn't start with an apostrophe, OP also says that, _I need to get all the word that contains apostrophe_.

Comment: Alright, I'm embarrassed for my carelessness. I forgot what you said at the beginning.